# Event on initial load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to catch the first load of a view using `ui-router` to show a login screen if a user is not logged in.

However `$stateChangeStart` is not firing on the first load, but it does on the following routechanges.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

How do I catch the initial load?

Answer (score 2):

```
 .when('/yourRoute', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/yourTemplate.html',
    controller: 'YourCtrl',
    resolve: {
      load: function ($route, ServiceExample) {
          return ServiceExample.start();
      }
    }
  })
```

You can use something like that to launch a method before loading a page.

Here, when you type /yourRoute in the browser, start method will be executed. Then the page will be displayed.

You can verify a user is logged in this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of resolve and can catch whether the user is logged in or not over there. Something like this:

```
.state('layout',{
    url:'/',
    abstract:true,
            resolve:{
            //Have your logic here to check for login cred and if there is none do a state change
        }
    },
    templateUrl:'startPage/layout',
    controller:'commonController'   
  })
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. how would the resolve:{} look?